# My HTML Tags won't be stripped from $this->username

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I am trying to strip my tags because someone keeps hacking my website by using the old ">blah as their username. For some reason my `strip_tags()` is not stripping the tags, but the `addslashes()` is working.

I don't know if I left off a bracket - but here is the code:

```
     public function register() {
    $correct = false;
        try {
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $this->username = strip_tags($this->username);
            $this->username = addslashes($this->username);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO User_Agents(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
 }
```

This is what it turns out to when it goes into my database:

[image: Picture of what it entered]

Comment: Why not simply reject usernames containing characters like this?

Comment: Well tbh I really didn't think of it, but I wouldn't know where to go about doing that...How could I make an if(){ } statement to do that?

Comment: try `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->username);`

Comment: You can use a regular expression, something along the lines of if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+$/", $username)); this  regular expression will only allow letters, digits, dots, and underscores.

Comment: Didn't work, same result..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: Thank you @Cristik Your method worked the best for me. I denied myself from making ">Iwannahackyou but allowed Test to join my website. Thanks a LOT (I don't know how to rep you - so tell me how lol)

Comment: Glad it helped, I posted an answer with this info, if you want you can accept and up-vote it, thanks.

Comment: I don't have 15 rep yet, just joined, but I accepted it, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply disallowing usernames that can lead to problems might be a more simple/efficient solution. For example a `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+$/", $username)` would allow you to reject usernames that contain other characters than letters, digits, dots, or underscores.

Answer (score 0):

The `strip_tags()` function is not the best way to go about this - I would not be sure it would strip a `>` closing tag if there is no corresponding `<` opening tag, for example.

In any case there's nothing inherently wrong with angle brackets and quote marks for usernames, as long as you render them correctly in your output code.

Something like this will do the trick (adjust the HTML type and character set to suit):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($username, ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```